# Pass Mongodb Atlas Operator env vars from travis to kubernetes deploy.sh

Tags: kubernetes, travis-ci, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to adapt the quickstart guide for Mongo Atlas Operator here [Atlas Operator Quickstart](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-atlas-operator-kubernetes) to use secure env variables set in TravisCI.

I want to put the quickstart scripts into my deploy.sh, which is triggered from my travis.yaml file.

My travis.yaml already sets one global variable like this:

```
env:
 global:
    - SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Which is consumed by the deploy.sh file like this:

```
docker build -t mydocker/k8s-client:latest -t mydocker/k8s-client:$SHA -f ./client/Dockerfile ./client
```

but I'm not sure how to pass vars set in the Environment variables bit in the travis Settings to deploy.sh

[image: env vars]

This is the section of script I want to pass variables to:

```
    kubectl create secret generic mongodb-atlas-operator-api-key \
  --from-literal="orgId=$MY_ORG_ID" \
  --from-literal="publicApiKey=$MY_PUBLIC_API_KEY" \
  --from-literal="privateApiKey=$MY_PRIVATE_API_KEY" \
  -n mongodb-atlas-system
```

I'm assuming the --from-literal syntax will just put in the literal string "orgId=$MY_ORG_ID" for example, and I need to use pipe syntax - but can I do something along the lines of this?:

```
echo "$MY_ORG_ID" | kubectl create secret generic mongodb-atlas-operator-api-key --orgId-stdin
```

Or do I need to put something in my travis.yaml before_install script?

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:04:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:39:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm64"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `echo` approach is fine, I've found a similar use-case to yours, have a look [here](https://drew-buckman.medium.com/use-travis-ci-to-automate-the-deployment-of-a-python-app-to-ibm-code-engine-4b534b503055).